# Automatically fix 'invalid-envvar-default' (W1508) pylint issue

Tags: python-3.x, pylint

Is there any way to automatically fix '[invalid-envar-default](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/warning/invalid-envvar-default.html)' pylint issue?

None of the tools that I tried (autopep8, autoflake and black) do not automatically fix this issue.

The solution seems to be pretty straightforward for all cases, ensuring the second parameter is a string (it could be just wrap it with `str()`:

Going from:
`os.getenv('SECRET_KEY', 1)  # [invalid-envvar-default]`

to: `os.getenv('SECRET_KEY', '1')`

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Let me clarify the question. But basically, none of the tools that I know to automatically fix lint issues (autoflake, autopep8) are capable of fixing this issue. I'm asking if there is an automated way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

pylint does not have autofix at the moment. ruff aim to do that, but has few lints available at the moment (and not 'invalid-envar-default'). It's likely that this kind of check will be dropped from pylint or not implemented in ruff because it's really really close to what a type checker should do generically applied on a single parameter of a single function. It feel like a remnant of time when type checker where not available. (source: I'm a pylint maintainer and I'm thinking about removing this check outright).

So to sump up, the optimal way to fix this right now is manually.